# "E:Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list" how to fix?

Tags: software-sources

I have recently installed PlayOnLinux on my Ubuntu 13.04, but I am getting a system error:

```
E:Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
/playonlinux.list
```

Please tell me how to fix it.

Here is the `html` file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://airtelforum.com/main?InterceptSource=0&
ClientLocation=in&ParticipantID=kk7rp2jf3dkl4v52nla5u7676ej8r6uf&FailureMode=1&
SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fdeb.playonlinux_jaunty.list%2F&AddInType=4&
Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0"/>
<script type="text/javascript">url="http://airtelforum.com/main?InterceptSource=0&
ClientLocation=in&ParticipantID=kk7rp2jf3dkl4v52nla5u7676ej8r6uf&FailureMode=1&
SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fdeb.playonlinux_jaunty.list%2F&AddInType=4&
Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0";if(top.location!=location){var 
w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,b=d.body,x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||b.clientW
idth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||b.clientHeight;url+="&w="+x+"&
h="+y;}window.location.replace(url);
</script>
</head><body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please paste the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` ? I suspect that it is an HTML file, instead of a text file.

Answer (score 2):

The link in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` is a link for Ubuntu 9.04, which is an End-of-Life release and unsuitable for the version of Ubuntu that you are using, Ubuntu 13.04. You can safely delete the file by running the following command from the terminal:

```
sudo rm '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list'
```

Then you will no longer get the error message.

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 14 as well...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an html file to the `sources.list`, this is not the correct format. All the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` should follow a syntax or it won't work. The correct syntax is:

```
deb http://domain.org/ubuntu release section #for binaires
deb-src http://domain.org/ubuntu release section # for sources
```

I recommend removing the file or following the correct syntax:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list"
```

Or just removing the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
```

Comment: care to explain what part is duplicated?

Comment: Err... is just that?